# Div position in the schedule

Tags: javascript, html, css

I make a program to creating timetables for school and I hava a case that different event are in this same time. I'd like to set my events next to each other. Can I do it with css or I have to set my position in javascript.

I create my div in javascript

```js
function createDivEvent(event) {
  var d = new Date(event.date);
  var parent = document.getElementById(weekday[d.getDay()]);

  if(parent) {
    var start = new Time(event.startTime);
    var end = new Time(event.endTime);

    var div = document.createElement("div");


    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.class=event.id;
    a.innerHTML = event.subject.shortName + " (" + event.place.name + ")";
    a.id = event.id;
    a.style.top =  start.getPercent() + "%";
    a.style.height = (end.getPercent() - start.getPercent()) + "%";

    a.classList.add("event");

    a.appendChild(div);

    if(parent) {
      parent.appendChild(a);
    }

  }
}
```

[No I have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IihWX.png)

[But I want something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk0Wh.jpg)

Parent css:

```css
div.day-of-week {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid var(--color-accent-bright);
}
```

Event css:

```css
a.event {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: var(--light-text-color);
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 99999px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
```

```js
var columnDayName = ['MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY'];

        var weekday = new Array(7);
        weekday[0]=  "SUNDAY";
        weekday[1] = "MONDAY";
        weekday[2] = "TUESDAY";
        weekday[3] = "WEDNESDAY";
        weekday[4] = "THURSDAY";
        weekday[5] = "FRIDAY";
        weekday[6] = "SATURDAY";


        var FIRST_COL_WIDTH_PROC = "5";
        var NUMBER_OF_ROW_TIME = 48;  // every half an hour
        var FIRST_COLUMN_ID= 'firstColumn';

        var START_TIME = new Time('0:00');
        var END_TIME = new Time('24:00');

        var SPACE = "\u00A0";

        var currentMonday = getLastMonday(new Date());

        var selectedSchoolId;
        var selectedClassId;

        var vm = this;

        vm.timetables = [];
        vm.schoolList = [];
        vm.lessonList = [];
        vm.classFromSchoolList = [];
        vm.timetablesOfDivisionList = [];

        loadAll();

        function loadAll() {
          console.log("re")
            createHeaderCalender();
            createColumn();
            drawTimeInFirstColumn();
            getTimetablesAndDrawNew();


        }


        function getTimetablesAndDrawNew() {
            var start = currentMonday.toISOString().split("T")[0];
            var endDate = new Date(currentMonday);
            endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 6);
            var end = endDate.toISOString().split("T")[0];
          
            var event = {
              color:null,
              date:"2016-10-25",
              endTime:"03:20",
              id:1522,
              startTime:"02:35",
              title:null,
              type:"LESSON"
            }
            
            var event2 = {
              color:null,
              date:"2016-10-25",
              endTime:"03:35",
              id:1523,
              startTime:"02:50",
              title:null,
              type:"LESSON"
            }
          
            vm.timetablesOfDivisionList = [];
            vm.timetablesOfDivisionList.push(event)
            vm.timetablesOfDivisionList.push(event2)
            drawTimetables();

        }

        function drawTimetables() {
            vm.timetablesOfDivisionList.forEach(function(timetable) {
                createDivEvent(timetable);
            });
        }


        // =============================================================================================================
        // Date
        // =============================================================================================================
        function getLastMonday(date) {
            date.setDate(date.getDate() - (date.getDay() + 6) % 7);
            return date;
        }


        function changeDateInHeader() {
            var date = new Date(currentMonday);
            columnDayName.forEach(function (day) {
                var dateText = date.toLocaleDateString();
                document.getElementById(day + "-header").innerHTML = dateText;
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
            });
        }

        // =============================================================================================================
        // Div Creator
        // =============================================================================================================
        function createDiv(position, id, parent, styleClass, top, left, height, width) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.classList.add(styleClass);
            div.id = id;
            div.style.position = position;
            div.style.top = top;
            div.style.left = left;
            div.style.width = width;
            div.style.height = height;

            //div.innerHTML = id;

            document.getElementById(parent).appendChild(div);
        }

        function createDivColumn(id, left) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            var columnWidth = ((100 - FIRST_COL_WIDTH_PROC) / columnDayName.length) + "%";
            div.classList.add("day-of-week");
            div.id = id;
            div.style.left = left;
            div.style.width = columnWidth;
            //div.innerHTML = id;

            document.getElementById("bg-timetable").appendChild(div);
        }

        function createDivFirstColumn(id) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");

            div.classList.add("day-of-week");
            div.classList.add("first-column");
            div.id = id;
            div.style.width = FIRST_COL_WIDTH_PROC + '%';
            //div.innerHTML = id;

            document.getElementById("bg-timetable").appendChild(div);
        }

        function createDivTime(id, parent, top, height, isHour) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.classList.add("hour");

            if(top==="0%") {
                div.classList.add("first");
            }

            if(!isHour) {
                div.classList.add("half");
            }

            div.id = id;
            div.style.top = top;
            div.style.height = height;
            //  div.innerHTML = id;
            document.getElementById(parent).appendChild(div);
        }

        function createDivEvent(event) {
            var d = new Date(event.date);
            var parent = document.getElementById(weekday[d.getDay()]);

            if(parent) {
                var start = new Time(event.startTime);
                var end = new Time(event.endTime);
                var div = document.createElement("div");

                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.class=event.id;
                a.innerHTML = event.id;
                a.id = event.id;
                a.style.top =  start.getPercent() + "%";
                a.style.height = (end.getPercent() - start.getPercent()) + "%";
                a.classList.add("event");

                a.appendChild(div);

                if(parent) {
                    parent.appendChild(a);
                }

            }

        }




        function createHeaderColumn(date, day, left) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            var columnWidth = ((100 - FIRST_COL_WIDTH_PROC) / columnDayName.length) + "%";
            div.classList.add("day-of-week");
            div.style.left = left;
            div.style.width = columnWidth;
            div.id = day + "-header";
            document.getElementById("calender-header").appendChild(div);
        }





        // =============================================================================================================
        // Creator
        // =============================================================================================================

        // =================================
        // Header
        // =================================
        function createHeaderCalender() {
            var date = new Date(currentMonday);
            var columnWidth = (100 - FIRST_COL_WIDTH_PROC) / columnDayName.length;
            var currentWidthPos = 0;
            currentWidthPos += +FIRST_COL_WIDTH_PROC;

            columnDayName.forEach(function(day) {
                createHeaderColumn(date, day, currentWidthPos + '%');
                currentWidthPos += +columnWidth;
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
            });

        }


        //
        // =================================
        function createColumn() {
            var columnWidth = (100 - FIRST_COL_WIDTH_PROC) / columnDayName.length;
            var currentWidthPos = 0;

            createDivFirstColumn('firstColumn');
            createTimeDiv(FIRST_COLUMN_ID);
            currentWidthPos += +FIRST_COL_WIDTH_PROC;

            columnDayName.forEach(function(day) {
                createDivColumn(day, currentWidthPos + '%');
                currentWidthPos += +columnWidth;
                createTimeDiv(day)
            });

        }

        function createTimeDiv(day) {
            var rowHeight = 100.0 / NUMBER_OF_ROW_TIME;
            var currentHeightPos = 0;

            for(var i=0; i <=NUMBER_OF_ROW_TIME -1; i++) {
                createDivTime(day + i , day, currentHeightPos + "%", rowHeight + "%", i%2!=0);
                currentHeightPos += rowHeight;
            }

        }

        function drawTimeInFirstColumn() {
            for(var i=0; i <=NUMBER_OF_ROW_TIME -1; i++) {
                if(i%2==0) {
                    document.getElementById(FIRST_COLUMN_ID + i).innerHTML = i/2 + ":00&nbsp;";
                }
            }
        }

        // =============================================================================================================
        // Time -> 12:34 String
        // =============================================================================================================
        function Time (time) {

            this.time = time;
            this.hour = parseInt(time.split(':')[0]);
            this.minut = parseInt(time.split(':')[1]);

            Time.prototype.getPercent = function() {
                return 100 * this.getMinutes() / (END_TIME.getMinutes() - START_TIME.getMinutes());
            };

            Time.prototype.getMinutes = function() {
                return this.hour * 60 + this.minut;
            };

            Time.prototype.addMinutes = function(minutes) {
                this.minut += minutes;
                this.changeMinutesToFormat();
            };

            Time.prototype.changeMinutesToFormat = function() {
                this.hour += parseInt(this.minut/60);
                this.minut = this.minut%60;
            };
        }
```

```css
:root {
    --primary-text-color: #212121;
    --light-text-color: #FFFFFF;
    --secondary-text-color: #757575;
    --divider-color: #BDBDBD;
    --dark-primary-color: #1976D2;
    --primary-color: #2196F3;
    --light-primary-color: #BBDEFB;
    --accent-color: #FFC107;
    --color-accent-bright: rgb(200,200,200);
}

div.bg-timetable {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
}

div.day-of-week {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid var(--color-accent-bright);
}

div.hour {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-accent-bright);
}

div.calender-header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


div.event:hover {
    box-shadow:none;
}

a.event {
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    color: var(--light-text-color);
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 99999px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}


a.event:hover {
    box-shadow:none;
}

.day-of-week.first-column {
    border-left: 1px solid var(--color-accent-bright);
    text-align: right;
}

.hour.first {
    border-top: 1px solid var(--color-accent-bright);
}

.hour.half {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed var(--color-accent-bright);
}
```

```html
<div>

    <div id="calender-header" class="calender-header"/>
    <div id="bg-timetable" class="bg-timetable"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Which plugin are you using for the calendar? Can you create a runnable snippet (or jsbin or something)?

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question, could you clarify? What have you tried and what exactly isn't working?
Of course you can set the offset to the right with CSS, but since you don't want that happening to every element you will probably need js to implement it. I'd suggest saving the timeslots and comparing for each new element you are creating. If it intersects with another time slot, add a class that offsets it, or just set left: x% via js.

Comment: I edited my post. I'm not using any plugin for calendar and I'd like to my event which are in this same time will be next to each other (like in google calendar)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk0Wh.jpg